# How to search for line breaks within XML text (within tags)?

Tags: c++, regex, xml, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I've massive XML-file with text blocks and many of them contain unencoded line-breaks.
How to search line-breaks (/n) within XML text (within tags) and replace it with HTML-encoded line-breaks like `&#10;` ?

My code so far:

```
#include <regex>
...
std::string sInput_xml;
std::ifstream in(sFilePath_XMLFile);

// read file into input_xml
while(getline(in, sLine))
    sInput_xml += sLine;

std::regex rxSearch("\>.*(\n)+.*\</");
std::regex_replace (sInput_xml, rxSearch,"&#10;");
```

... and then I'd like to pass the string to the rapid-xml parser. Unencoded line-breaks are ignored by this (and many other) parser and I tried to replace it manually with `&#10;`. It works perfectly but the file is 31k lines, it would take forever.

I'm not even sure if this regex is correct but my the VS compiler complains about the search_replace function not taking three params. But the should be a 3 param version like in the example on [cplusplus regex replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_replace/).

Comment: You mention `within tags`, but your regex implies between tags (content).  Also is regex available in VS2010 ? I use that compiler and I have to use Boost because its not c++11. In addition, if not Dot-all mode, `.*` will blow right past and into the middle of tags if some on same line.

Comment: Yes, <regex> is available https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-AT/library/bb982382.aspx , I get some warnings because of the escape sequences, but they can be disabled.

Comment: That link you reference says VS2013, not VS2010 that you tagged in the question. I think VS2010 doesn't actually have c++11 in it.

Comment: You are right, 
I'm glad softwariness pointed me to  a solution without using any regex.

Comment: @sln The regex library was in VS 2010, but it's a bit flaky. There a bunch of C++11 features in 2010 (despite the year), as people had been waiting expectantly for the new C++ standard for a long time.

Comment: @softwariness - I use VS2010 C++ exclusively, how would I invoke this regex library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using RapidXML 1.13, an XML file with unescaped newlines in elements and attributes is parsed successfully, and the attribute and element values preserve the whitespace for me, so I think the search and replace is unnecessary.

Note that if you're debugging in Visual studio, the newlines are omitted from the tooltip when you hover over a variable in the editor, maybe that's what led you to believe they weren't preserved.

Regarding your problem with the `regex_replace` function, if you use an `std::string` for the third parameter it will compile. This seems to be a problem in Visual Studio 2010, as the `const char*` is accepted in Visual Studio 2013.

You will also need to be aware of characters to be escaped in both the search and replace strings if you still want to go down the regex route.

UPDATE: Now I realize that was representative code of how you were loading the file before introducing the regex, you should be aware that `getline()` does not include the newline, so it is your loading code which is removing the newlines from the file. Simplest thing would just be to use RapidXML to do the file loading directly:

```
#include "rapidxml_utils.hpp"
// ...
rapidxml::file<> xmlFile("test.xml");
rapidxml::xml_document<> doc;
doc.parse<0>(xmlFile.data());
```

Comment: I need the actual line break later in the presentation  of this text. The creator of the xml files simply serialized data from a vintage database and has forgotten about the preformatted text it contains. 
In order to present this text, I need to preserve the line breaks and replacing the text before parsing seems the best idea to me.
I use rapidxml 1.13 and if I use it like in the sample code above (ignore the regex stuff), it has removed all unencoded line breaks when I access the text via DOM.

Comment: I understand your problem now, and have updated my answer with the solution.

Comment: Thanks, this works just fine!
I didn't think it will be that easy, but on the other hand I've never taken a look at rapidxml_utils.hpp.

Perhaps edit your solution you'll have to include rapidxml_utils.hpp.

Comment: Good point, now added - and on reflection I see your point about the header file naming being a bit counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for using c++ ?

maybe you can try sed

```
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/&#10;/g' input.xml
```

the -i flag edit file in place, so make sure you have a backup before you run that.

reference
 [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n)